The issue of custom properties in SpringBoot
SpringBoot Version:2.7
application.yml:
urban:
  cas:
    ticket-url: http://${URBAN_CAS_TICKET_URL:10.64.9.33:8780}/cas

@Value("${urban.cas.ticket-url}")
private String ticketUrl;

When the URBAN_CAS_TICKET_URL property is not set in the environment variables, the printed result is as follows:
http://10.64.9.33:8780/cas
However, if the URBAN_CAS_TICKET_URL is set in the environment variables:
URBAN_CAS_TICKET_URL=127.0.0.1:8080
The printed result becomes:
127.0.0.1:8080
This is not the desired result because it loses the "http://" at the beginning and "/cas" at the end.
I want to know why it loses "http://" and "/cas"? Or how can I prevent this loss?

$URBAN_CAS_TICKET_URL (env), @Value("${urban.cas.ticket-url}") (value) and urban:cas:ticket-url (yaml) are all the same property to Spring.

In your case, you are completely overwriting the property urban.cas.ticket-url with the environment property URBAN_CAS_TICKET_URL. In Spring, you can use underscores in place of dots and dashes in property names, making these two properties identical.
You should consider using two different names (e.g., urban.cas.ticket-url and urban.cas.host). This should resolve the issue.
Source:
Spring Boot Externalized Configuration

If you use environment variables rather than system properties, most operating systems disallow period-separated key names, but you can use underscores instead (for example, SPRING_CONFIG_NAME instead of spring.config.name). See Binding From Environment Variables for details.


If you will replace underscore(_) with dot(.) in your env variable like this URBAN.CAS.TICKET.URL. Your problem will be resolve
urban:
  cas:
    ticket-url: http://${URBAN.CAS.TICKET.URL:10.64.9.33:8780}/cas

